# How to manage cookie in silverlight out-of-browser application

Tags: silverlight, cookies, out-of-browser

I have a out-of-browser application where I store some values in the cookie but on application exit it deletes all the cookie values.
So anyone can help me on this.I need the cookie values again the aaplication lunched in out-of-browser mode.

I have read this link
http://forums.silverlight.net/t/180264.aspx/1

Is this the final answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Isolated Storage Instead a cookies. You can use it for saving data in file. It will be stored in hard drive and will be avaible after restarting the Application.

Comment: More information: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/16/tip-of-the-day-19-using-isolated-storage.aspx